# Set the table name for all entities in Entity framework 5

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I've created a EF6 application, pointing to a mysql database. I created a global rule for setting the table name based on entity class name, so a entity called UserDocument would automatically point to a table named user_document. I used the following code

```
public class ComplianceDB : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c => c.ToTable(GetTableName(c.ClrType)));
    }

    private string GetTableName(Type type)
    {
        return Regex
            .Replace(type.Name, ".[A-Z]", m => m.Value[0] + "_" + m.Value[1])
            .ToLower();
    }
```

Its working in EntityFramework 6, but now I have to downgrade to EF5 due to hosting limitations (FullTrust), And when I changed the reference to EF5 I got the message:

```
'DbModelBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Types' and no accessible extension method 'Types' accepting a first argument of type 'DbModelBuilder' could be found
```

How can I set the table name for all entities in EF5?